# Wifi on my laptop drops after just less than a minute, while the network manager still says "connected"

Tags: wireless, internet, realtek-wireless

I recently installed ubuntu on my new laptop. I'm having the usual struggles getting all the things working, and the latest one is the WiFi. For some reason, my internet connection drops shortly after connecting to the WiFi (but not always! sometimes it lasts for a longer time); what is weird is that my laptop is actually still connected to the WiFi, I just lose the connection to the internet.
I'm sure it's not a problem of my network, because with the ethernet or other PCs it's all good.

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8821]
    Subsystem: XAVi Technologies Corp. RTL8821AE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [1b9a:2482]
    Kernel driver in use: rtl8821ae
    Kernel modules: rtl8821ae
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader [10ec:5287] (rev 01)
```

Comment: Config problem between your system and your router seems the most logical answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command.

Comment: This is the kernel driver issue. What is the Ubuntu and the kernel version?

Comment: 4.10.0-21-generic, ubuntu 18.04

Comment: There is no 18.04. Probably 17.04?

Comment: of course, 17.04, somehow I fatfingered that :P

Answer (score 2):

I suggest disabling `FW control power save` by running

```
sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ae.conf <<< "options rtl8821ae fwlps=0"
```

Reboot to apply.

Comment: It seems to be working. I will be sure about it when some more time has passed!

Comment: Nope... As soon as i wrote that the connection dropped... now I'm on back on my ethernet.

Comment: Did you run the command, if not, run it again. Then reboot. The connection could not drop "because you wrote it".

Comment: And please don't "write it", copy and paste it.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself. By "wrote that" I mean the comment where I said "It seems to be working".
I did copy-paste your code and rebooted. The connection stayed up for 5 minutes and then dropped.

Comment: There are some other parameters that can be tuned. I suggest reporting a bug to Launchpad. These Realtek chips are troublesome. To remove my setting run `sudo rm /etc/modprobe.d/rtl8821ae.conf`